# apache rewrite rule to redirect only .aspx urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi I am replacing an existing windows server with a linux website and need to reroute any links that someone might have laying around in the form of mysite.com/folder/somename.aspx

What I need to do is grab everything after the domain and redirect it to the new windows server that hosts the previous application

Now I have the following which does not seem to be working

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=10
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.aspx -f
RewriteRule ^mysite.com/(.*)$ https://new.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Oh I forgot this happens to be a wordpress site ugh!

Answer (score 0):

You don't want any host information in the URI pattern in a rewrite rule, all of that is matched against the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable using a rewrite condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.aspx -f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://new.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```